# Monad Transformers

Tags: haskell, comparative-review, monads

I've run into the same scenario involving Monad Transformers a few times now, and I'm looking for some "best-practice" advice.

Bear with the introduction, the issue itself is really simple:

---

Say you're given a list of inputs, and you want to convert them into some aggregated form while handling the possibility of invalid inputs. In code, we could have something like:

```
type Input = String
type ProcessedInput = String
type Output = S.Set ProcessedInput
data Error = InvalidFormat Input
           | DuplicateInput ProcessedInput

processInput :: Input -> Maybe ProcessedInput

-- Useful later, not vital to the problem
ifM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m a -> m a
ifM cond t f = cond >>= \c -> if c then t else f
```

and we want something like:

```
buildInputs :: [Input] -> Either Error Output
```

I've found that it's normally nicer to compute this inside a little isolated monad transformer stack (`StateT` around an `Except`, so we can build up our result and handle errors when needed) instead of doing a bunch of maps and `any` checks and aggregations.

So the question: **Is it "better" to express this computation as acting on *single inputs*, or acting on the *entire input***? Bearing in mind that this is an entirely self-contained computation, it won't need to be used as a subcomputation anywhere else.

---

Using a "single-input" action requires some slightly unintuitive wrapping in `buildInputs`:

```
buildInputs :: [Input] -> Either Error Output
buildInputs is = runExcept $ execStateT builder S.empty
        where builder = sequence (map buildInputs' is)

buildInputs' :: Input -> StateT Output (Except Error) ()
buildInputs' i = case processInput i of
                    Nothing -> throwError (InvalidFormat i)
                    Just p  -> ifM (gets $ S.member p)
                                       (throwError $ DuplicateInput p)
                                       (modify $ S.insert p)
```

---

Using a "whole-input" action gives a cleaner wrapper at the cost of a messier body:

```
buildInputs :: [Input] -> Either Error Output
buildInputs is = runExcept $ execStateT (buildInputs2' is) S.empty

buildInputs' :: [Input] -> StateT Output (Except Error) ()
buildInputs' [] = return ()
buildInputs' (i:is) = case processInput i of
                        Nothing -> throwError (InvalidFormat i)
                        Just p  -> do
                                    ifM (gets $ S.member p)
                                            (throwError $ DuplicateInput p)
                                            (modify $ S.insert p)
                                    buildInputs' is
```

---

Is there a best-practice convention for this sort of thing? Is there an entirely better way of doing this that I've missed?

<sup>[Complete code here](https://pastebin.com/qsu04UGx)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop in the second one is precisely what combinators like `sequence` and `map` are meant to capture and factor away. Thus, I find the first version is more idiomatic.

It's always possible to turn a program on single inputs to one on whole inputs by wrapping it in a loop like your second snippet does, but not the other way around in general, because a program on lists might make non-trivial use of the remaining tail (`is`). In that sense, your first version contains more information, that is lost when transforming it into the second one, and keeping it may thus improve readability: we know more about what the function cannot do.

---

On a smaller scale, `sequence` and `map` together are also called `traverse`, and since in this case we are collecting the results in a separate structure we only need a fold (`traverse_`) rather than a traversal, which puts the individual `()` outputs in a list. Here again, by using a more general function, we signal that the "regular output" of the computation (that would be `[()]`) is irrelevant.

When the loop body (`buildInputs'`) is small and called only at one location, it may be worth inlining it, and `for_` is sometimes nicer than `traverse_` for that (`for_ = flip traverse_`) and makes the code look nicely imperative when it is meant to be.

The pattern-match on the result of `process` could also be refactored to be quieter.

```
buildInputs :: [Input] -> Either Error Output
buildInputs is = runExcept (execStateT go S.empty) where
  go = for_ is $ \i -> do
    p <- processInput i `ifFail` throwError (InvalidFormat i)
    collides <- gets $ S.member p  -- The variable name tells what this is checking
    when collides $ throwError (DuplicateInput p)
    modify $ S.insert p

ifFail :: Applicative m => Maybe a -> m a -> m a
ifFail (Just a) _ = pure a
ifFail Nothing oops = oops
```